# What Point co-ordinates does StartPosition.CentreScreen translate to

Tags: winforms

On a Windows Form you can set the `StartPosition` enumeration property to `CenterScreen` to have the form start in the center of your primary monitor.

I understand from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx) that when selecting one of the StartPosition enumeration values, behind the scenes the `Location` property of the form is set to an instance of the `Point` class, which obviously takes two integers as values in the constructor, to set the position of the form.

If you select the `Manual` enumeration of `StartPosition` you can set the `Location` property to an instance of the `Point` class yourself, positioning your form wherever you like.

I am trying to get my Windows Form to always start in the top center of my screen using [the Dell Dock](http://www.delldock.com/images/version15d/dell_dock.jpg) as my inspiration. So my question is, what co-ordinates are used by the compiler to position the form at the center of your screen whenever you select `CenterScreen` as your `StartPosition`?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit on an open question. It is very possible to create docked applications using both technologies. There are a number of controls and libraries available for both, and a  quick internet search for docking controls with give you many results.

Comment: I've made the question more specific

Comment: Since a form is positioned using the top left corner (0,0) you need to use the formula - `ScreenWidth / 2 - FormWidth / 2` to get the center point - not sure where you'd get the screen width but that's the general rule. The top of your form would likely just be at position 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can get the screen size using one of these:

```
SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
SystemInformation.WorkingArea
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

Then just set the form position to the centre using the formula

```
ScreenWidth / 2 - FormWidth / 2
```

You can set the forms top position to 0 assuming you want it centred at the top